Inconsistent pipe result when using zsh and bash
The command is pretty simple:
echo 123 >/dev/null | cat

If you run in bash, it will show nothing. This is what I expected.
However, when I run this in zsh, it will show 123. This is very surprising for me. Because it seems zsh pipes the stdout before redirection.
If I understood correctly, zsh can duplicate the stream for free (e.g by doing echo 123 2>&1 >&2 | cat). But in bash we need to use tee.
Just wonder if someone can explain the differences?

Zsh supports multios, bash doesn't. What more is there to explain?

@Kevin : You are right of course, but I think this is not all too obvious. May I suggest that you write it as answer instead of just a comment, and perhaps also point out how MULTIOS can be turned off?

That shuffle works in bash, too (it just makes standard IO point the same file as standard output, then writes to standard error intead of standard output), but the duplicate output seen is still a product of multios.
